# xslt find and replace regex-lookarounds

Tags: regex, xslt, xslt-2.0, regex-lookarounds

I have a problem with `XSLT replace()`.

`XML`:

```
<root>
<title>I am title</title>
<body>
the new formula is:<br/>
the speed test 234 km/h<br>
the weight is 49 kg<br/>
in the 1492 Lorenzo de Medici die.
etc.
<dida>the mass is 56 kn</dida>
</body>
</root>
```

I must replace all the space after number of measure system.

In `PHP` I found this regex:

```
((?<=\d)\s(?=km|kg|kn))
```

In `XSLT` I have:

```
<xsl:template match="//*/text()">
<xsl:value-of select="replace(., '\(\(?\<=\\d\)\\s\(?=km\|kg\|kn\)\)', '&nbsp;')"></xsl:variable>
</xsl:template>
```

The problem is `<` character!

Comment: Generally the XPath regex syntax is a subset of what PHP and Perl allow, and you mustn't assume that you can simply reuse a PHP regex in this way. Usually there is another way of achieving what you want, often simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common notation for '<' inside a literal string is `&lt;`

That, however, didn't fix it for my XSLT processor (Kernow, using Saxon 9.1.0.3). As it appeared, it doesn't need all those escapes for parentheses and vertical bars. In addition, the lookarounds didn't work. I was able to solve this using

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(., '(\d)\s(km|kg|kn)', '$1!$2')"></xsl:value-of>
```

(replacing with a '!' for clarity).

There are a few other basic errors in your example which I had to fix first: `<br>` was not correctly closed, and you mustn't terminate `<xsl:value-of ..` with `</xsl:variable>`.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! The xml is only example and in copy and paste from xslt I make mistake